# Color Excel rows based on text cells

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to color rows of data based on some key terms in column A.
Some rows need to be green and some rows need to be red.

I found this online but when I run it nothing happens on the sheet. I don't really know why or how to fix it. This is the version from my excel sheet, so it has all my info in it.

```
Public Sub ColorCHange2()
    Dim mapping As Object, itm As Variant
    
    Set mapping = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    mapping(XlRgbColor.rgbLightPink) = Array("exclude from emails","exclude from listings")
    mapping(XlRgbColor.rgbLightGreen) = Array("include in billing list","include in emails")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
    With Sheet1.UsedRange
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        For Each itm In mapping
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criterial1:=mapping(itm), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Interiror.Color = itm
            
        Next
        .AutoFiler
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You have at least 2 typos in the code: `Criterial1` and `Interiror`

Comment: Why VBA for this? This can be done with conditional formatting

Answer (score 4):

Fixing your typos and the the fact your code doesn't only color visible cells post-filter...

```vb
Public Sub ColorCHange2()
    Dim mapping As Object, itm As Variant, rngVis As Range
    
    Set mapping = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    mapping(XlRgbColor.rgbLightPink) = Array("exclude from emails", "exclude from listings")
    mapping(XlRgbColor.rgbLightGreen) = Array("include in billing list", "include in emails")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
    With Sheet1.UsedRange
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        For Each itm In mapping
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=mapping(itm), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            Set rngVis = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rngVis = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rngVis Is Nothing Then rngVis.Interior.Color = itm
        Next
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```